# Is memory better used with a bunch of if else statements or seperate methods for each?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If i have a method that has 50 if else statements would it be better on the memory management to make each one a separate method?  and then call them by method instead of passing a variable to just one method to decide which one to use?

```
- (int) whatItems:(int) number{

int value=0;
//finds random number between 0-9999
value = (arc4random() % 10000);
//what item did you find?
//1=chopping a tree
if (number==1)
{
    if (value>5000) {
        return 1;//found wood
    }
    else if (value<=5000){
        return 2;//found eggs
    }
}
//2=digging dirt
else if (number==2)
{
    if (value>=2000) {
        return 0;//found nothing
    }
    else if (value<=1000){
        return 3;//found mushrooms
    }
    else if (value>1000&&value<2000)
    {
        return 4;//found gold
    }
}
//3=Open The First Chest
else if (number==3)
{
    return 5; //return axe
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't focus on memory management at this point. I would focus on writing maintainable and concise code (i.e. don't have 50 if-else statements in a single method).

Answer (score 1):

One function is preferable.  Each function call requires the creation of and destruction of a stack frame for the function.  In doing this, you will still be sending all 50 variables to a function over time, bit you'll also be making the frame modifications.  Doing one function will only require one frame creation and then the pushing of the variables.

The BEST solution, however, would be to pass your function one pointer to a structure of some kind that contains all of your data.

Comment: Premature optimization and trying to out-guess the compiler is best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrate on clean readable, understandable code, not on optimization. Later look for performance issues with Instruments, it will almost always be somewhere else.

Premature optimization is evil and non-productive.